# How can I mock a constructor when it appears as a method reference in a stream?

Tags: java, java-8, junit4, powermock, powermockito

I'd like to test the constructor of the following class `Foo`.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Foo {
    public List<Bar> bars;

    public Foo(List<Integer> list) {
        bars = list.stream()
                   .map(Bar::new)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

where `Bar` looks like this:

```
public class Bar {
    public Bar(Integer baz) {
        throw new RuntimeException("This crashes, but who cares, I’m testing Foo!");
    }
}
```

As I have full confidence in the implementation of `Bar`, I'd like to test my implementation of `Foo` by mocking `Bar::new`.

Here is what I tried:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Foo.class) // where Bar::new is referenced
public class FooTest {
    @Test
    public void testFoo () throws Exception {
        Bar firstBar = PowerMockito.mock(Bar.class);
        Bar secondBar = PowerMockito.mock(Bar.class);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(Bar.class).withArguments(1)
                .thenReturn(firstBar);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Bar.class).withArguments(2)
                .thenReturn(secondBar);

        Foo actual = new Foo(Arrays.asList(1, 2));

        Assert.assertNotNull(actual);
        Assert.assertNotNull(actual.bars);
        Assert.assertEquals(firstBar, actual.bars.get(0));
        Assert.assertEquals(secondBar, actual.bars.get(1));
    }
}
```

In this case, the actual `Bar::new` is called, and the `RunTimeException` is raised. This makes sense in retrospect, as the actual call to new is not made in `Foo` (where it would be mocked), but in some anonymous class related to streams (I *think*).

How can I achieve my original goal of testing `Foo` without relying on the actual implementation of `Bar`’s constructor?

Comment: Show the exception stacktrace and which line in the test it fails.

Comment: Anyway... it is bad idea to mock this way. If you are using powermock, you either trying to work with legacy code, or just doing something very wrong.

Comment: @kan. I dont think it is bad idea to mock `Bar`. It is a dependency and should not be tested when testing `Foo`.

Comment: @kan It fails with `"java.lang.RuntimeException: This crashes, but who cares, I’m testing Foo!"`at `Bar.<init>(Bar.java:3)` at `java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)`

Comment: what a good question!

Comment: @tsolakp It is good idea to test, correct. But it is bad idea trying to mock object constructors. It is better to use some kind of factory pattern and inject it instead of relying on byte-code hacks done by powermock.

Comment: A) nice question ... but then B) follow the answer you got. Not needing PowerMock is *always* a good thing.

Comment: @kan. Ability to unit test should not drive the implementation. Just because we can't mock something does not mean we have to change the implementation.

Comment: @tsolakp - I disagree. You never heard of TDD? If it is difficult to test, it will be difficult to use and maintain.

Comment: @It is a slippery slope to blindly follow your rule. According to that logic we should never create dependent object directly and should use some type of factory pattern. That sure will increase difficulty of maintenance.

Comment: @tsolakp If we want to test object creation - then we should able to mock it and it means we could put some other object - so we need a factory. But there is no reason to use factories to create something like `ArrayList`. So, yes, I would say it should be a design decision.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've figured out that's going on. The expression `Bar::new` is a lambda which PowerMock fails to mock. If you rewrite it as `i -> new Bar(i)` i.e. with the explicit "new Bar" operator - it works fine.

So, the point is AVOID USING POWERMOCK - it is bad!! See my another answer.

Comment: Yeap, same behavior with EasyMock using PowerMock.But I would not stop using PowerMock because of it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a trivial refactoring to extract Bar factory and you don't need do anything with powermock hacks.

```
class Foo {
    public List<Bar> bars;
    // existing constructor
    public Foo(List<Integer> list) {
        this(list, Bar::new);
    }
    // constructor which trivial to test.
    public Foo(List<Integer> list, Function<Integer, Bar> barFactory) {
        bars = list.stream()
                .map(barFactory)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree for both "simple refactoring" and "dont use powermock". Still this doesn't really answer the question ... it doesn't tell us how to use powermock and that method reference ;-)